# memcpy() crashes randomly

Tags: c++, memcpy

I am using memcpy in my application. memcpy crashes randomely and below is the logs i got in Dr.Watson files.

```
        100181b5 8bd1             mov     edx,ecx
        100181b7 c1e902           shr     ecx,0x2
        100181ba 8d7c030c         lea     edi,[ebx+eax+0xc]
        100181be f3a5             rep     movsd
        100181c0 8bca             mov     ecx,edx
        100181c2 83e103           and     ecx,0x3
FAULT ->100181c5 f3a4             rep     movsb  ds:02a3b000=?? es:01b14e64=00
        100181c7 ff1508450210     call    dword ptr [Debug (10024508)]
        100181cd 83c424           add     esp,0x24
        100181d0 6854580210       push    0x10025854
        100181d5 ff1508450210     call    dword ptr [Debug (10024508)]
        100181db 83c404           add     esp,0x4
```

Below is the code

```
memcpy((char *)dep + (int)sizeof(EntryRec) + (int)adp->fileHdr.keySize, data, dataSize );
```

Where:

- dep is a structure
- EntryRec is a charecter pointer
- adp is a structure
- data is not `NULL` in this case

Has anyone faced this issue and can help me?

I have tried to debug the prog,
then i got the following error
Unhandled exception in Prog.exe(MSVCRTD.DLL):0xC0000005: Access voilation

Data is passed argument for this program and this is void*

**Further Info:**

I have tried to Debug the code adapter is crashing in the following area this function is present in OUTPUT.c (I think this is a library function)

```
#else  /* _UNICODE */
            if (flags & (FL_LONG|FL_WIDECHAR)) {
                if (text.wz == NULL) /* NULL passed, use special string */
                    text.wz = __wnullstring;
                bufferiswide = 1;
                pwch = text.wz;
                while ( i-- && *pwch )
                    ++pwch;
                textlen = pwch - text.wz;
                /* textlen now contains length in wide chars */
            } else {
                if (text.sz == NULL) /* NULL passed, use special string */
                    text.sz = __nullstring;
                p = text.sz;
                while (i-- && *p) //Crash points here
                    ++p;
                textlen = p - text.sz;    /* length of the string */
            }
```

Value for variables:
p= ""(not initialised)
i= 2147483598

Comment: I think we need to see the code

Comment: the bug is not memcpy, we would need to see your code probably a bad pointer or buffer overrun into the stack or other memory.

Answer (score 17):

There are two very likely explanations:

1. You are using `memcpy` across overlapping addresses -- the behavior of this situation is undefined.  If you require the ability to handle overlapping addresses, [`std::memmove`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memmove) is the "equivalent" tool.
2. You are using `memcpy` to copy to/from memory that is inaccessible to your program.

From the code you've shown, it looks like (2) is the more likely scenario.  Since you are able to debug the source, try setting a breakpoint before the `memcpy` occurs, and verify that the arguments to `memcpy` all match up (i.e. `source + num < dest` or `source > dest + num`).

Answer (score 10):

From the disassembled code it appears that the source pointer is not in your address space.
rep movsb copies from ds:si to es:di. The ?? indicates that the memory at ds:si could not be read.

Answer (score 2):

Is the data pointed to by `(char *)dep + (int)sizeof(EntryRec) + (int)adp->fileHdr.keySize` always at least `dataSize` long?

I have come across similar crashes where variable length strings are later treated like fixed with strings.

eg

```
char * ptr = strdup("some string");
// ...
memcpy(ptr, dest, fixedLength);
```

Where `fixedLength` is greater than `10`.  Obviously these were in different functions so the length issue was not noticed.  Most of the time this will work, `dest` will contain "some string" and after the null will be random garbage.  In this case if you treat dest as a null terminated string you will never notice, as you don't see the garbage after the null.

However if `ptr` is allocated at the end of a page of memory, you can only read to the end of the allocated memory and no further.  As soon as you read past the end of the page the operating system will rightly crash your program.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've run over the end of a buffer and generated an access violation.

Edit: There still is not enough information.  We cannot spot a bug without knowing much more about how the buffer you are trying to copy to is allocated whether it has enough space (I suspect it does not) and whether dataSize is valid.

Answer (score 1):

If memcpy crashes the usual reason is, that you passed illegal arguments.

Note that with memcpy source and destination may not overlap.

In such a case use memmove.

Answer (score 1):

from your code "memcpy((char *)dep + (int)sizeof(EntryRec) + (int)adp->fileHdr.keySize, data, dataSize)" and the debug infomation, the "data" looks like a local variable (on-stack variable), you'd do "data = malloc(DATA_SIZE)" instead of "char data[DATA_SIZE]" etc; otherwise, at your current code line, the "data" was popped already, so may cause memory accessing fault randomly.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using memmove as this handles overlapping strings, when using memcpy in this situation the result is unpredictable.